# Does Thread.sleep have no effect in Stream processing?

Tags: java, java-stream

The following program is from OCP Study Guide by Jeanne Boyarsky and Scott Selikoff:

```
import java.util.*;

class WhaleDataCalculator {
    public int processRecord(int input) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Handle interrupted exception
        }
        return input + 1;
    }

    public void processAllData(List<Integer> data) {
        data.stream().map(a -> processRecord(a)).count();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WhaleDataCalculator calculator = new WhaleDataCalculator();
        // Define the data
        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
            data.add(i);
        // Process the data
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        calculator.processAllData(data);
        double time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0;
        // Report results
        System.out.println("\nTasks completed in: " + time + " seconds");
    }
}
```

The authors claim

> Given that there are 4,000 records, and each record takes 10
> milliseconds to process, by using a serial stream(), the results will
> take approximately 40 seconds to complete this task.

However, when I am running this in my system, it is taking between 0.006 seconds to 0.009 seconds on every run.

Where is the discrepancy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because of the use of `count`, which performs a trick in later Java versions.

Since you're only interested in the number of elements, `count` will try to get the size directly from the source, and will skip most other operations. This is possible because you are only doing a `map` and not, for example, a `filter`, so the number of elements will not change.

If you add `peek(System.out::println)`, you'll see no output as well.

If you call `forEach` instead of `count`, running the code will probably take 40 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The call of `.map(a -> processRecord(a))` did not run at all, the reason is because you are running this program with a JDK version more than 1.8.

Let's take this example to make it easy to understand:

```
long number = Stream.of("x", "x", "x").map(e -> {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            return e;
        }).count();
        
        System.out.println(number);
```

Try to run it using a JDK 1.8 , after that run it using a JDK 11.

In java 8, count() acts as a terminal operation, all the intermediate operations(map method here) will be executed, the  map operation will be executed and will print the hello message. you will get this output:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
3
```

In greater than 1.8 Java versions, 11 as example here, Java can determine the number of elements of the stream directly, if there is no intermediate operation that can change the number of the elements of the stream (example : filter() ), no intermediate method will be executed, just the count method will be executed, so you will not see any hello message but the number of the element of this stream will be calculated and you can use it. your output will be like that:

```
3
```

If you like to see the hello message in the Java versions greater than 1.8, you should add an intermediate operation to your stream pipeline that can change the number of element of the stream, let's add the filter method to the pipeline and see the output on java 11:

```
long number = Stream.of("x", "x", "x").map(e -> {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            return e;
        }).filter(element-> element.equals("x")).count();
        
        System.out.println(number);
```

Here the output:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 9 operation `count()` has been optimized in such so that if during the initialization of the stream (when stages of the pipeline are being chained) it turns out that there are no operations which can change the number of elements in the stream source allows evaluating the number of elements it contains, then `count()` does not trigger the execution of the pipeline, but instead asks the source "how many of these guys do you have?" and immediately returns the value.

So while running `processAllData()` a `Stream` instance would be constructed and right after that the method would terminate, because none of the elements would be actually processed.

Here's a quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count()):

> **API Note:**
>
> An implementation may choose to not execute the stream pipeline
> (either sequentially or in parallel) if it is capable of computing the
> count directly from the stream source. In such cases no source
> elements will be traversed and no intermediate operations will be
> evaluated. Behavioral parameters with side-effects, which are strongly
> discouraged except for harmless cases such as debugging, may be
> affected.For example, consider the following stream:
>
> ```
>  List<String> l = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
>  long count = l.stream().peek(System.out::println).count();
> ```
>
> The number of elements covered by the stream source, a `List`, is known
> and the intermediate operation, `peek`, does not inject into or remove
> elements from the stream (as may be the case for `flatMap` or `filter`
> operations). Thus the `count` is the size of the `List` and there is no
> need to execute the pipeline and, as a side-effect, print out the list
> elements.

And by the way, besides the trick behind this test, this case doesn't require the usage of Stream API. Since the value returned by `count()` is ignored and everything that is need is to fire a side-effect on each element of the list, then [`Iterable.forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) can be used instead:

```
public void processAllData(List<Integer> data) {
    data.forEach(a -> processRecord(a));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. However, you missed to quote the relevant information, which is: *An implementation may choose to not execute the stream pipeline (either sequentially or in parallel) if it is capable of computing the count directly from the stream source. In such cases no source elements will be traversed and no intermediate operations will be evaluated.*

Comment: @Beginner Agree, there was a bit of a mess with the quote, updated the answer.